# Visual Studio 2012 Nuget "The remote name cannot be resolved"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I can't get any packages through NuGet as Visual Studio. The remote name that cannot be resolved is for an old proxy at a our company, but I'm using a direct to internet connection here. Is there a way to change the internet settings in Visual Studio to not use a proxy at all? I've tried nslookup and the IP matches that from the internet and another linux machine on the same network.

VS was installed behind the proxy server using that gateway, so we're getting to the disk through the post, reinstall point.

All other internet functions are working correctly and I can get nuget.org through a browser.
Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the global Internet explorer options were still locked to use the old VPN. In VS2012 go to Environment/ Web server and change your settings there to not use a VPN. You will also have to look at the LAN settings too.